# Ubuntu 18.04 Displays Issue -> Unknown Display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, display

As the title suggests, I am experiencing issues with my Display in Ubuntu 18.04.
I have seen somewhat related posts (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053088/ubuntu-18-04-unknown-display) one), but those typically suggest they have several detected displays, where one of them is dubbed 'Unknown Display'.

Well, I only have a single display called 'Unknown Display', which means I:

- cannot add a second/third/etc screen,
- cannot adjust the resolution,
- and cannot adjust the brightness

I would very much like to be able to do the above, obviously, and I was hoping somebody over here might be able to help me out.
I have tried out several things, like removing the current drivers in favor of older ones, but I seem to be missing something crucial every time..

Here are some specifics about my system:

- I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
- I have a `GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]` graphic card.
- I have `nvidia-driver-396` installed.
- It is a dual boot system, where I left the original Windows copy intact.

Some potentially interesting stats:

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
steven@stevens-laptop:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1
```

`xrandr` output:

```
steven@stevens-laptop:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

`nvidia-settings` output:

```
steven@stevens-laptop:~$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

If any additional info is needed to figure out what's going on, please let me know. And thanks in advance for any help on this!

Here is a screenshot of the 'Settings -> Devices -> Displays' window in my Ubuntu by the way:
[image: display-settings]

Comment: Steven, I do have the same issue, did you get a perfect solution for this problem??

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you @AnoopSankar, but I haven't managed to fix this problem at all... I am however pretty confident it's the lack of support on Acer's, the laptop I was using, in my case. I eventually just gave this computer to another employee and bought a different one (sad but true...).

Two of the provided answers did help out others though, so maybe those will solve your problem.

Answer (score 35):

I had this problem and removing the monitors.xml config didn't work.

there was a problem w/ the nvidia driver. check to see by running

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and if that looks good

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

should do the trick

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Although this originally didn't work, I reinstalled 18.04 recently (with the same screen issues still in place, mind you) and now my NVidea Settings do work!
So, one step in the right direction, but now my second screen is still not being recognize :[ Nonetheless, the help is much appreciated @Even W!

Comment: To be more exact, the message I now receive when running `nvidia-settings` is the following:
```
steven@steven:~$ nvidia-settings 
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:2986): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:57:33.804: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: The `autoinstall` + reboot worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: You saved my life, thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04... still works! I think what happened is an apt upgrade caused a new initrd image to be created that was booted from, and it had the wrong graphics properties set.  I ran the commands above, then made sure to run `sudo update-grub`, and then `cat /proc/cmdline` to verify the initrd image matched, then rebooted... and all my monitors came back online with expected resolutions.

Comment: also worked for me, I've ubuntu 20.24, and nvidia+nouveau driver. The monitor became unknown suddenly and `autoinstall`  fixed it.

Comment: perfect, this worked for me, just installing then reboot

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by deleting the configuration file (resetting) for the display settings:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for that Dustin!
I had 3 `monitors*.xml` files in my `~/.config/` directory, all with some weirdness in it.
Removing them however did not do the trick...

Nonetheless, the response is much appreciated of course.

Comment: omg, this deleted everything on my desktop.  And my Firefox bookmarks.

Comment: I copy pasted and added <disabled> section: <configuration>
<logicalmonitor>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<scale>1</scale>
<primary>yes</primary>
<monitor>
<monitorspec>
<connector>default</connector>
<vendor>unknown</vendor>
<product>unknown</product>
<serial>unknown</serial>
</monitorspec>
<mode>
<width>1920</width>
<height>1080</height>
<rate>77</rate>
</mode>
</monitor>
</logicalmonitor>
<disabled>
<monitorspec>
<connector>eDP</connector>
<vendor>BOE</vendor>
<product>0x0812</product>
<serial>0x00000000</serial>
</monitorspec>
</disabled>
</configuration> to monitors.xml

Answer (score 2):

I think this is for the one's who didn't solve there issues by the above suggestions.

I got the same. I just changed the grub file

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

and changing the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: What does `nomodeset` do?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem - all of a sudden, when I booted the computer this morning, my Samsung 40" TV had turned into "Unknown Display" and I have no idea why.

Then I found this question and tried to debug according to the first answer - so after `lspci` I ran `xrandr` and suddenly boom!, it worked!

I still have no idea why, but I suspect it could be a kernel (i.e., a missing kernel update) thing.

Answer (score 0):

This command plus a reboot fixed the issue for me.

`sudo apt full-upgrade -y`