# How to reset window initial position

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-control-center

I have Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade from 18.04, now every time I launch gnome-control-center, the initial window position is outside of the screen (right side), I have to used short key `Alt + F7` to move into the screen to do the rest of settings.

I didn't have dual monitor.

I have tried reset all the settings by the following methods, but it didn't work.

`$ dconf reset -f /org/gnome`

or

`$ gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.shell`

Similar issue happened in gnome-nautilus, but I got this fixed by

`$ gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.nautilus`

How to make an gnome app initial window location to its default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your brief description, it **sounds** like your gnome-control-center window is launching to another workspace than you'd like.

If that's really the case, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to move into the "screen" where the gnome-control-center window is, then hit the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key, click and drag the gnome-control-center window into the desired workspace on the right side of the screen. Click <kbd>SUPER</kbd> to close the overview.

Comment: I looks like the app is launched into an unknown display. I saw there is an `unknown display` plus a builtin display under the `Display` setting entry. I guess the nvidia driver not work properly after upgrade. After do `ubuntu-drivers devices` to check and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install, then reboot, the unknown display is gone, only one builtin display, and all apps work fine now. See also [Unknown display in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069451/ubuntu-18-04-displays-issue-unknown-display)