# Low display resolution in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on two different desktop computers and encountered the same problem: the monitor is shown as "unkonwn display" and the resolution is fixed at 1024x768(4:3) and can not be changed, with my second monitor being not detected.

When installing, I opt to install all the non-free third-party drivers, so I expect the monitors should work out of box.
I also installed Ubuntu 20.04 on two laptops, where the monitors work perfect.

My impression is that this version of Ubuntu is focused on laptops while has some obvious problems that can arise in desktop computers not taken care of.

Before posting this, I read the following question and all the answers: [Ubuntu 18.04 Displays Issue -> Unknown Display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069451/ubuntu-18-04-displays-issue-unknown-display)

About 15 years ago, I often had hardware problems when I installed a linux distribution on various computers. This kind of problem seems to have disappeared in the last decade: hardware always work out of box. So I do not expect I need to manually install drivers for a particular device after a fresh installing. I think the hardware I am using is not weird enough that is unable to be automatically handled by the installer.

I tend to consider the above problem as a bug recently introduced in the ubuntu distribution

Comment: No, I don't think any version of Ubuntu has been "focused on laptops".  I've used it with a desktop for many years and haven't had any problems with the last few years.  Of course, it does require some work depending on how "common" is your setup.  That's what sets Ubuntu apart from other commercial OS'.

Comment: Only hardware that is certified Ubuntu is supposed to work out of the box.  If you feel that this is a bug please file it with Canonical by running `ubuntu-bug ubiquity`.  We are not Canonical employees in here, we are only volunteers to help you if you need.

Comment: @Terrance  I know my question is more like an expression of feeling rather than asking for help. Even Canonical employees are not responsible for providing technique support for me since I did not pay.

Comment: @YoujunHu Regarding your update to your post, 15 years ago was a very long time.  I would argue that Linux (any distribution) is still not yet at a stage where it works "out of the box".  That's for more commercial OS' because, as you pointed out, you pay them.  Also, they have the resources to approach video card vendors to find out how to work with them before either is sold.  So, you need to approach Linux very differently.  Indeed, this forum isn't a place to "express your feelings".  But, in the future, if you give a detailed explanation of what you're facing, someone might help...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution:

settings->about>software Updates->additional drivers

then choose the nvidia driver metapackage marked as (proprietary and tested).