# ASUS VA249 HE monitors on ASUS PRIME Z690-P D4 Motherboard

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, asus

I have dual monitor setup. Both monitors are Asus models VA249 HE.  They are connected to the Display and HDMI ports of the Asus Motherboard.  I am running Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

When I boot with one monitor the options to control the display are limited. I can't adjust the resolution. [image: Ubuntu Screen Display]

If I plug both monitors I get a mirrored display. The option to extend the display is not available.

How I can resolve this please?

---

[Link to the Monitor Specifications -- VA249HE](https://www.asus.com/displays-desktops/monitors/all-series/va249he/techspec/)

---

**Additional Information**

The video is on the Intel CPU.

According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/230500/intel-core-i713700k-processor-30m-cache-up-to-5-40-ghz.html) is it Intel® UHD Graphics 770

Output of Ubuntu Commands

*lspci | grep VGA* :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a780 (rev 04)
```

*xrandr* :

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080     77.00*

*sudo lshw -c video* :

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

*-graphics
product: EFI VGA
physical id: 2
logical name: /dev/fb0
capabilities: fb
configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

*ubuntu-drivers devices* :
<< no output >>

*sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall* :

```
All the available drivers are already installed.
```

Comment: "Unkown Display", your system is not recognizing the display you are using. Have you tried installing available drivers? Look into it and update your question. I see that ASUS does not provide drivers for that display, but maybe some third-party does? Beware of the risk of using those.

Comment: I can plug the monitor into my Windows computer (migrating from a Windows environment to Ubuntu) but other than that I don't really know how to go about this.  In Windows it is transparent and I never had to deal with drivers.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069451/ubuntu-18-04-displays-issue-unknown-display . Update the question if any of the answers helped. Have in mind that Ubuntu is not Windows, drivers may differ, that's why maybe Windows works out of the box with your display config.

Comment: I followed the link.  I updated the original question to add clarity.  Point to note:  The video is Intel on the CPU.  I also added the output of various commands that the poster of the link you shared had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the guide at [How to Identify & Find Graphics Drivers for Linux](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005520/graphics.html)
and the monitor is identified.

Dual Monitor Setup is working.

[image: AsusTek Computer Inc 24"]

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Seemed like a clear problem related to drivers. I should've asked (or at least thought) about your graphics card, experience for the future, though.

Comment: It makes one wonder how the drivers of a company such as Intel would not be packaged and detectable out of the box.  But the community was fantastic.